# c# Excel How to find a specific range without looping through every row/record

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm making a tool that checks if an existing excel file (>20k records) contains a specific string in a specific column.
So far I've tried using a for-loop to check every single cell, but it took almost 2 minutes to find the the cell.

example:

```
row     name    price
-------------------------
7000    AAA     10
7001    AAA     5
7002    AAA     10
7003    AAA     5
7004    AAA     10
7005    AAA     10
7006    AAA     10
7007    BBB     5
7008    BBB     5
7009    AAA     10
7010    BBB     5
...
30000   AAA     10
```

my pseudo-code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
            var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"A_PATH");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            var xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int lastRow = xlWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
            for (int i = 2; i < lastRow; i++) {
                if(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null) {
                    string value = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
                    if(value == "BBB") {
                        Console.WriteLine(((Excel.Range)xlRange.Cells[i, 3]).Value2.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

So is there a way i can make the 'query' faster instead of reading every row?
I know in SQL there's something like index skip scan. Maybe I can achieve the same in c#.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe sorting the strings at first and then making a binary search provides a better result. I know that it provides a better result but I don't know if you're able to change the location of rows. If it is not a problem for you, try sorting rows and make a binary search.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)?

Comment: I don't really know what binary search is, I googled it quickly but it is possible if you have a predefined list like List<string>(). So basically I have to add every result from the forloop in the list and only after that I can do the binary search. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Andrew I looked it up yes, but will it really work? For example: http://i.imgur.com/KjjjZmv.png
Lets assume "BBB" is at cell 1 and the last cell, the range will still go from start to entireColumn, no?

Comment: Edward, no I don't mean to load all texts within cells to a memory list, use xlRange.Sort(...) method to sort cells on the excel document, then implement a basic binary search algorithm. A simple implementation is documented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm. Iterative approach would be easier to adapt on your case. Yes this approach needs to loop through cells several times for sorting. But after sorting once, you'll find what you look in a very short time.

Comment: @Edward It is likely to be faster to get Excel to do the search rather than passing the value of each cell to your code.

Comment: @Andrew is Range.Find an Excel function? sorry for my lack of knowledge on this subject, I'm pretty new to this office 'framework' :s

Comment: @Edward Did the link I gave earlier to [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) not work?

Comment: @Andrew I tried it but it didn't give the desired output without a huge workaround, the solution posted by Stephen Byrne did work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not terribly good with Excel automation, but perhaps you could try using the built-in Excel filter function?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    namespace ExcelTest1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                excel.Visible = true;
                var book = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\test.xlsx");
                var sheet = book.Sheets[1];
                var range = sheet.UsedRange;

                //Filter the sheet itself.                
                range.AutoFilter(Field: 2, Criteria1: "BBB");
                //and get only visible cells after the filter.
                var result = range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
                Console.WriteLine(result.Rows.Count);
                foreach (Range row in result.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells[1,3].Value2());
                }
                book.Close(SaveChanges:false);
                excel.Quit();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

On a modest system, this found "BBB" which was the last of 30,000 rows of test data, in under a second.

Comment: I'm testing this as we speak, but it looks like this is heading to the right direction, thanks! If this ended up working ill flag this as the solution :)

Comment: Works like a charm and indeed with the real data took it only 1 second. Thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped.